# OkHttp CookieJar fails to add cookie to request

Tags: java, cookies, kotlin, okhttp

I'm trying to add a saved authentication cookie to further requests by utilizing a CookieJar. And while getting a correct authentication cookie and saving it to the jar is working great, when inspecting the `response.request().headers()`, the cookie is nowhere to be found.

I found this especially strange since I found out by debugging that `loadForRequest()` is called for the request and returns that correct cookie. When using that exact same cookie in Postman to fake the request, it returns the desired result (a page without a login form).

Could someone try to explain what I'm missing?

**Class where the jar is utilized**

```
class HTMLRoutes {
    var scheme = "https"
    var host = "www.mangaupdates.com"
    val cookieJar = MULoginCookieJar()
    var client = OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .cookieJar(cookieJar)
            .build()
/*Other code*/

private fun getHTMLFromUrl(url: HttpUrl): String {
        var request = Request.Builder()
                .url(url)
                .build()
        client.newCall(request).execute().use { response ->
        //Right before returning response the loadForRequest() method gets called in the MUCookieJar class
            if (response.isSuccessful) {
            //response.request.headers = ""
                if (response.body() != null) {
                    return response.body()!!.string()
                } else {
                    throw IOException("Response body is empty")
                }
            } else {
                throw IOException("Unexpected code" + response)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**My cookiejar**

```
class MULoginCookieJar : CookieJar {
    private var secureSessionCookie: Cookie? = null

    override fun saveFromResponse(url: HttpUrl?, cookies: MutableList<Cookie>?) {
        if (url != null && cookies != null) {
            if (url.pathSegments().size > 0 && url.pathSegments()[0] == "login.html") {
                for (cookie in cookies) {
                    if(cookie.name() == "secure_session") {
                        secureSessionCookie = cookie
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    override fun loadForRequest(url: HttpUrl?): List<Cookie>? { // url = https://www.mangaupdates.com/series.html?id=14829
        if(url != null && url.pathSegments().size > 0 && url.pathSegments()[0] == "login.html") {
            return emptyList()
        }

        val cookies: List<Cookie> = if(secureSessionCookie==null) emptyList() else listOf(secureSessionCookie!!)
        return cookies // = ["secure_session=601bbc74; expires=Sun, 07 Oct 2018 20:45:24 GMT; domain=www.mangaupdates.com; path=/; secure; httponly"]
    }
}
```

Help is immensely appreciated. I have been a long time lurker but this is the first time I have been this stumped at a problem.

Comment: What are you doing to check that the cookie isn’t being sent? Note that depending on your configuration an interceptor might run before cookies are added to the request.

Comment: @Jesse Wilson When debugging at right after the response has been returned at `client.newCall(request).execute().use { response ->`, the OkHttp Response stored in `response` has an empty string for `response.request.headers`. I don't know if this is a definitive way to assure that the cookie wasn't sent but I feel like there should be a `Set-Cookie.......` in the headers if the cookie was sent? I also don't curently have an Interceptor in my implementation. Are you suggesting to add one?

Comment: Same for the response.networkResponse().request() ?

Comment: @Jesse Wilson No. The cookie is in the `networkResponse().request().headers()`. I have also just discovered that when I manually add the cookie as a header to the request that the desired result is returned. A suggestion on how I can fix this without hardcoding the cookie into the request?

Comment: The network request is the one that gets sent to the server. This might help: https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Calls

Answer (score 6):

I would recommend using an existing cookie jar instead of creating your own. The rules around cookies can get a bit complex.

```
import okhttp3.JavaNetCookieJar;

CookieManager cookieManager = new CookieManager();
cookieManager.setCookiePolicy(CookiePolicy.ACCEPT_ALL);
JavaNetCookieJar cookieJar = new JavaNetCookieJar(cookieManager);

OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().cookieJar(cookieJar).build();
```

Also to help debug you can set up [OkHttp debug logging with an interceptor](https://www.stubbornjava.com/posts/okhttpclient-logging-configuration-with-interceptors).

```
Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HttpUtil.class);
HttpLoggingInterceptor logging =
    new HttpLoggingInterceptor((msg) -> {
        logger.debug(msg);
    });
logging.setLevel(Level.BODY);

client.addNetworkInterceptor(logging);
```

Answer (score 0):

I expereienced the same "problem" but it turned out that it was not because the Cookie didn't get set. It just weren't shown because at this point

```kotlin
OkHttpClient.Builder()
    .cookieJar(SessionCookieJar())
    .addNetworkInterceptor(
        HttpLoggingInterceptor().apply {
            setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.HEADERS)
        }
    )
    .build()
```

, whatever Interceptor one uses, it must be added as "NetworkInterceptor" in order to let it see the Cookies loaded by the `CookieJar`. Maybe it help someone.